# How to use a dynamic path expression in Xquery

Tags: path, expression, xquery, dynamic, assign

I'm fairly new to xquery so please bear with me as I try to best ask this question.

when i use the following statement (to select a sequence) it works just fine:

```
let $parts := doc("soap.xml")/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns0:PartDetails/ns0:partName
```

this loads all elements (as a sequence) into the $parts variable just how i'd like but...

i want to assign the "`/ns0:partName`" **dynamically**. I went thru all the Qname functions thinking they'd somehow help but no such luck. after 2 days of struggling i'm hoping one of you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

In your path expression, you can replace element with * and add predicates in order to filter the results, predicates may contain dynamic variables. For example :

```
*[local-name()=$someName and namespace-uri()=$someURI]
```

Comment: i was able to use the "*[local-name()=$someName]" portion and it worked very nicely. tytyty!

Answer (score 2):

As a simplication to vincent's answer you can just check that an xs:QName matches the node-name() of the node

```
let $elementName = QName("urn:namespace", "PartDetails")
...
let $parts := doc("soap.xml")/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*[node-name() = $elementName]/ns0:PartName
```